# CLPlacemark from Place could not map the selected Place

Tags: ios, objective-c, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm implementing google places autocomplete api for `MapKit` in iOS 7 by using [SPGooglePlacesAutoComplete](https://github.com/spoletto/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete) github library.
After carefully implementing everything the final stage where I want to move my `Annotation` to the selected place by the user it gives the error `Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=8`. 
 This happens after user selects a particular location from the autocomplete result. So this is what I'm doing in my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
SPGooglePlacesAutocompletePlace *place = [placesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[place resolveToPlacemark:^(CLPlacemark *placemark, NSString *addressString, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        SPPresentAlertViewWithErrorAndTitle(error, @"Could not map the selected Place");

    }else if (placemark) {

        [selectedPlaceAnnotation setCoordinate:placemark.location.coordinate];

        locationLat = selectedPlaceAnnotation.coordinate.latitude;
        locationLon = selectedPlaceAnnotation.coordinate.longitude;

        [defaults setFloat:locationLat forKey:@"locLat"];
        [defaults setFloat:locationLon forKey:@"locLon"];


        selectedPlaceAnnotation.title = @"You Selected This Location";

        if (![self.MapView.annotations containsObject:selectedPlaceAnnotation]==YES) {
            [self.MapView addAnnotation:selectedPlaceAnnotation];
        }

        //[self.MapView animateToLocation:placemark.location.coordinate];

        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(placemark.location.coordinate, 800, 800);
        [self.MapView setRegion:[self.MapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];


            [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
        }
}
     ];
```

If I print `resolveToPlacemark` parameters I'm getting this `Placemark = (null) Address String = (null) Error = Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=8 "(null)"`

Comment: can you please check the object place?

Comment: @VishnuKumar.S place object is printing the right value which I selected from the search result.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `searchQuery.types` to `SPPlaceTypeGeocode` if it is set to `SPPlaceTypeEstablishment`.

Comment: I've solved it... It was a mistake with `searchQuery.types` which was set to `SPPlaceTypeEstablishment` I just changed it to `SPPlaceTypeGeocode` and now it's working

Comment: Ok, happy to hear that your issue is fixed :)

Comment: update what I wrote in your answer so that I can mark it correct.